# Show that if $(H+F)$ is nonsingular, it follows that $ H(H+F)^{-1}F=F(H+F)^{−1}H $

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a problem from my Linear Algebra course and I'm having trouble with this question. If anyone could help me I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Show that : $ H(H+F)^{-1}F=F(H+F)^{−1}H $ knowing that $(H+F)$ is non singular

I managed to do this by assuming that $H$ and $F$ were both individually nonsingular but I can't manage to find a way to solve it by only using the initial condition: $(H+F)$ nonsingular.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
H(H+F)^{-1}F&=&H\color{blue}{(H+F)^{-1}F}+\overbrace{F\color{blue}{(H+F)^{-1}F}-F(H+F)^{-1}F}^{=0} \\ 
&=&(H+F)\color{blue}{(H+F)^{-1}F}-\color{red}{F(H+F)^{-1}}F -\overbrace{\color{red}{F(H+F)^{-1}}H+F(H+F)^{-1}H}^{=0}\\
&=&F-\color{red}{F(H+F)^{-1}}(F+H)+F(H+F)^{-1}H \\
&=&F(H+F)^{-1}H.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: thanks for helping! can you please give me an extra step : how do you get $F(H+F)^{−1}(F+H)+F(H+F)^{−1}H $ from $−F(H+F)^{−1}F$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=H+F$, $F=A-H$. Then
$$
HA^{-1}(A-H)=(A-H)A^{−1}H \Leftrightarrow HA^{-1}A-HA^{-1}H=AA^{-1}H-HA^{-1}H
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow H-HA^{-1}H=H-HA^{-1}H
$$
which holds trivially. Hence the original equality holds.

Comment: yes but here you are also using that $AA^{-1} = I$ which is not given

Comment: @pGz $A=H+F$ is nonsingular by assumption so $AA^{-1}=I$.

Comment: oh yes sorry. thanks!

Comment: @pGz The assumption that $A=H+F$ is non-singular means that $A$ is invertible such that $A^{-1}=(H+F)^{-1}$ makes sense and $AA^{-1}=I=A^{-1}A$.